# Column header and columns are out of order and don't match using latest grid component in Chrome

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

After updating the angular grid component to version ~1.7, when I display data in the grid the columns are out of order and the column headers no longer match the data in the column. I have spent quite a bit of time testing and the following are my findings:

- If I limit the number of columns to 10, it works fine. Increasing the number of columns even by 1, to 11, causes it to fail.
- The same exact page works fine in Internet Explorer 11 and the latest Firefox.
- The order of the column headers is not random. The column headers are out of order in exactly the same way every time the data is loaded.
- The order of the grid columns, although they don't all match the order of the headers, are not random either. They are out of order in exactly the same way every time the data is loaded.
- I am using some logic to show a different template for the data based on whether the column is the first column or not using

```html
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of columndefinitions; let first = first" ...
```

The cell template looks like this:

```html
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
   <div>
      <a *ngIf="first" class="cellanchor">{{dataItem[column.name]}}</a>
      <span *ngIf="!first">{{dataItem[column.name]}}</span>
   </div>
</ng-template>
```

Even though the columns appear out of order, the column that should be first, shows up in the second column, but it uses the anchor dom node as though it were in the first column. To summarize, the data for the first column shows up as an anchor but is actually shown in the second column, not the first.

I am still doing further research, but am hoping this information will allow someone to identify a potential problem.

Additional Information (1/29):
As more information on this issue: In Chrome: if I interrogate the properties of the grid component in the browser debug tools, I notice that the order of the fields in the "columns" property is the intended order. The order of the fields in the "columnList" property is the order that is displayed for the content of the grid which does not match the "columns" property or the headers of the grid.
In Internet Explorer (where the grid appears to be working properly): the order of the fields in the "columns" property matches that of the "columnList" property which also matches the headers.

Why would the columnList property contain a different order of the fields from one browser to the next?

I have created a GitHub issue to track this problem: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1265

Comment: Additional Information:

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue, be sure to upgrade the kendo-data-query package to the latest version as well. That will eliminate this issue. At the time of this writing, the latest version was 1.1.2 of the kendo-data-query package. Thanks to the guys at Progress for the assistance!!